# Plone 4.3 without Archetypes

Tags: plone, dexterity

Is there a way to install Plone without Products.Archetypes - not just deactivating - only with Dexterity.

I think there was a way....

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish that cannot be accomplished by deactivating the Archetypes content types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

plone.app.contenttypes just deactivates the installed Archetypes. Since many packages in Plone 4.3 depend on Products.Archetypes and Products.ATContentTypes, there is no way of getting rid of the package entirely. You could try to uninstall Archetypes in the quickinstaller (ZMI), but I wouldn't expect that to work.

Bottom line is, I don't think it is worth the effort to even try. You wouldn't gain that much and the risk that your Plone site does not work afterwards is very high.

Comment: BTW, how about Plone 5? Does it only deactivate the installed Archetypes, too?

Comment: For what I know Plone 5 will be shipped with Archetypes but it will not be used by default.
Probably it will became an add-on framework from Plone 5.1 and after.

Comment: Yes. Plone 5 will ship with Archetypes and ATContentTypes. Both will just be deactivated and might become an optional add-on product at some point. We are not there yet and we still plan to support AT in the future.